# CoInitialize() has not been called exceptions in C++

Tags: c++, com, dllimport

-**My problem**

I got CoInitialize has not been called exption.

-**My project structure**

Here is my porblem. I have a COM dll, MCLWrapper.dll developped with C#; I have a nother native C++ dll, ThorDetectorSwitch.dll that calls MCLWrapper.dll; And finally, I have a console application TDSTest.exe that calls ThorDetectorSwitch.dll. Basically, something like this:

*TDSTest.exe (C++ console) -> ThorDetectorSwitch.dll (C++ native) -> MCLWrapper.dll (C#)*

---

Code in TDSTest.exe that loads the ThorDetectorSwitch.dll:

```
HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(_T("C:\\TIS_Nick\\Hardware\\Devices\\ThorDetectorSwitch\\TDSTest\\TDSTest\\Debug\\Modules_Native\\ThorDetectorSwitch.dll"));
```

Constructor in ThorDetectorSwitch.cpp

```
ThorDetectorSwitch::ThorDetectorSwitch() : _mcSwitch(__uuidof(MCLControlClass))
{
    _A  = WstringToBSTR(L"A"); 
    _B  = WstringToBSTR(L"B");
    _C  = WstringToBSTR(L"C");
    _D  = WstringToBSTR(L"D");

    _deviceDetected = FALSE;
}
```

The break point hits the first parenthesis of the constructor of the ThorDetectorSwitch.dll above, but the exception occurred immediately if I hit F10 (one more step)

It jumps to

```
 hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(IUnknown), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown));
```

in the comip.h. The hr is simply "CoInitialize has not been called".

I have been thinking abou this porblem for days, and cannot figure out a solution. Anyone here can sharing any thoughts? Really appreciate it.

Comment: I think you need to call  `CoInitialize()`. *Source: the error message freaking says "CoInitialize() has not been called"*

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I called CoInitialize() like Reed mentioned, but there is another problem. See my comments to Reed's.

Comment: `init_apartment();` probably wasn't called before using winrt components for those who run across this question when learning C++/WinRT. Just make sure that line runs first.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your COM dll requires you to be in Single-Threaded Apartment mode.  You need to call [`CoInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) prior to using it.

Add this to your .exe:

```
CoInitialize(nullptr); // NULL if using older VC++

HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibrary(_T("C:\\TIS_Nick\\...
```

Comment: How do I do that? Where should I add CoInitialize()? And how many of them I should be adding? Thanks.

Comment: @NickXTsui I typically put it right at the start of the entry point (`main()`), and only call it once.  It sets up *that thread*.  You might want to also add `CoUninitialize` to the end of your program, too.

Comment: @NickXTsui Just make sure `TDSTest.exe` calls this prior to using your DLL

Comment: I added CoInitialize(NULL) in TDSTest.exe before calling the COM dll, but now, the exception occurs in comip.h at hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, pOuter, dwClsContext, __uuidof(IUnknown), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pIUnknown)); The excution cannot pass this line.

Comment: @Copsy I think you are right. Calling CoInitialize() before call a COM dll is the right way to handle. Thanks.

Comment: I'm absolutely new to this c++ thing. just adding the first line reed suggested, did the trick.